# django get context from external app in main template

Tags: python, django

I have integrated [djangocms blog](https://github.com/nephila/djangocms-blog) in my project. In homepage sidebar i want to display latest blog posts. Problem is, my homepage is django-cms page and i can't get blog post objects. urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    .....
    url(r'djangocms_blog/', include('djangocms_blog.urls', namespace='djangocms_blog')),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),

)
```

Somehow here in main.html i should be able to get blog records:

```
    {% extends "base.html" %} 
<nav class="secondary-menu">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <!-- i need display them here -->
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Is there any elegant way to do this?

Comment: You can a [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/) - or you just use one of the provided Plugins and a cms [static placeholder](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.3.x/introduction/templates_placeholders.html#static-placeholders).

Comment: Tried with templatetags, but still doesn't work. I must be able to loop through posts in template. If i create template tag, let's say `get_latest_posts()` and return list of objects, i can't loop them. In template: `{% get_latest_posts as posts %}` throws an error `'get_latest_posts' received too many positional arguments`.

Answer (score 2):

Use either an `assignment_tag` or an `inclusion_tag`:

#### Templatetag

```
# templatetags/blog_tags.py
from django import template
from djangocms_blog.models import Post

register = template.Library()

@register.assignment_tag()
def latest_posts_as(limit=5):
    return Post.objects.order_by('-date_published')[0:limit]

@register.inclusion_tag('latest_posts.html', takes_context=True)
def latest_posts_inline(context, limit=5):
    qs = Post.objects.order_by('-date_published')[0:limit]
    context.update({'posts': qs})
    return context
```

#### Snippet for inclusion tag

```
<!-- latest_posts.html -->
{% for post in posts %}
    <p>{{ post }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

#### Your home/whatever template

```
<!-- your_template.html -->
{% load  blog_tags %}
<div>

    <!-- using assignment_tag -->
    {% latest_posts_as limit=20 as posts %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <p>{{ post }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

    <!-- using inclusion_tag -->
    {% latest_posts_inline limit=10 %}

</div>
```

The `limit` is optional - but could be handy :)

Answer (score 0):

Came up with other solution. Created new django-cms plugin:

```
class BlogLatestEntriesPluginNav(BlogLatestEntriesPlugin):
    name = _('Navigition latest blog entries')
    render_template = 'latest_entries_nav.html'

plugin_pool.register_plugin(BlogLatestEntriesPluginNav)
```

where `BlogLatestEntriesPlugin` is plugin from [djangocms_blog](https://github.com/nephila/djangocms-blog) app. And created new template `'latest_entries_nav.html'`. Then in `main.html`

```
<ul class="nav">
    {% placeholder "left_sidebar" %}
</ul>
```

created placeholder and added that plugin.